# Function to check if number is a prime number

Tags: python, boolean, primes

```
def is_prime(n):
   
    if n >= 2:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if not (n % i):
                return False
    else:
        return False
    return True
```

I was trying to make a code that would dheck if a number is a prime numeber. I found this code on the internet and it works great. However, I am relatively new to coding so I was wondering if someone could explain the final 2 lines for me. Why do you `return True` after `return False` ?

Comment: If the input is a prime number (or the  condition of ```if``` statement is satisfied) the ```else``` statement will not be executed and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the statement `if n >= 2`, you will notice that it does all the main computation for any number which is greater than `2`. What happens if the number `n` passed is less than 2? Well, the `else` statement is called. So, when `n` is either 0 or 1, you know it's not a prime number. Thus, **`return False`** is executed which tells that the number is not a prime number.

Coming to the other line. When all the computation is done and `return False` has not executed even once, the interpreter arrives at the last line of the function and executes **`return True`** which tells that the number is a prime number.

#### Examples

---

- When `n = 6`

  Statement `n >= 2` evaluates to **True**, so, the for-loop is executed. When the value of loop variable `i` is 2, the line `if not (n % i)` evaluates to True and then `return False` is executed which tells that `n` is not a prime number.
- When `n = 5`

  Statement `n >= 2` evaluates to **True**, so, the for-loop is executed. None of the values of `i` are divisible with `n`, hence, no return statement is executed. Finally, the last line of the function is reached and `return True` is executed which tells that `n` is a prime number.
- When `n = 0`

  Statement `n >= 2` evaluates to **False**. Thus, the `return False` statement under `else` statement is executed which tells that `n` is not a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

The `return False` is inside the `else` block, whereas the `return True` is only run if the `if` succeeds.

Another way of writing the same program

```py
def is_prime(n):
   
    if n >= 2:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if not (n % i):
                return False
        return True  # Return True here, instead of at the end
    else:
        return False
```

This does the exact same thing, I just moved the `return True` statement inside the first `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

`return True` tells python to return a boolean value of `True`, and `return False` tells python to return a boolean value of `False`. If calling the function with a certain number gives you `True`, that certain number is a prime number. Else, it is not a prime number.